# Is there a function in R to transpose variables, or column headers into one vertical column?

Tags: r, transpose

I have a dataset with over 1K variables. I would like to create a new data frame that transposes all variables into one column so I can better search through the variables. My intended result can be seen below. I do not need to have the observations included in the new DF.

Current Data

Var 1 | Var 2| Var 3| etc

The desired Outcome would be one variable column

**Column**

- Var 1
- Var 2
- Var 3

Comment: Yes - this is typically called "reshaping" or "pivoting" data from wide to long - the linked FAQ gives several options.

Comment: That would be  appropriate if you want the corresponding values. If you just want the column names you can extract them with `names(your_data)`. Or put them in a data frame: `your_variables = data.frame(names(your_data))`